# Python | Automatic DataFrame generation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two folders with images from city skylines two different daytimes (day and night). I want to read in all images in different color spaces in the corresponding folders and then I want to calculate statistics for all the color channels. Then I want to create a pandas data frame containing all statistics.

In order to prevent unnecessarily repeated code, I am trying to use dictionaries. At the moment I am able to print out all the statistics for all the combinations of color space x channel x statistic. But I conceptually fail to get this stuff into a pandas DataFrame with rows (separate images) and columns (filename, color_space x channel x statistic).

I would appreciate any help.

```
import os

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import pandas as pd


dictionary_of_color_spaces = {
    'RGB': cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB,  # Red, Green, Blue
    'HSV': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV,  # Hue, Saturation, Value
    'HLS': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS,  # Hue, Lightness, Saturation
    'YUV': cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV,  # Y = Luminance , U, V = Chrominance color components   
}

dictionary_of_channels = {
    'channel_1': 0,
    'channel_2': 1,
    'channel_3': 2,
}

dictionary_of_statistics = {
    'min': np.min,
    'max': np.max,
    'mean': np.mean,
    'median': np.median,
    'std': np.std,
}

# get filenames inside training folders for day and night
path_training_day = './day_night_images/training/day/'
path_training_night = './day_night_images/training/night/'
filenames_training_day = [file for file in os.listdir(path_training_day)]
filenames_training_night = [file for file in os.listdir(path_training_night)]

for filename in filenames_training_day:
    image = cv2.imread(path_training_day + filename)
    for color_space in dictionary_of_color_spaces:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, dictionary_of_color_spaces[color_space])
        for channel in dictionary_of_channels:
            for statistic in dictionary_of_statistics:
                print(dictionary_of_statistics[statistic](image[:,:,dictionary_of_channels[channel]]))
```

Comment: @anky_91 At the moment it is just an output with one statistic for each line. But I want a data frame. I think I could solve this issue by switching to numbers as iterators and then fill a predefined `np.zeros([rows, columns])`. But that solution is not elegant and rather implicit than explicit :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of without changing the bulk of your code would be:

- create an empty df whose columns are all combinations of statistic x channel x color_space (easily done with a list comprehension);
- for each image, append all statistics to a variable (`row`):
- cast `row` into a pd.Series object, using `row` as the values, columns of the dataframe as index and `filename` as its name;
- append the row to your empty df.

The most important detail is to get the df column names right, i.e. in the same order as the values which populate the `row` variable. When we create the combinations in the list comprehension for the column names, it's important that we move from the innermost loop to the outmost, in order to the values to match later when we append `row` into the df.

This should work:

```
import os

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import pandas as pd


dictionary_of_color_spaces = {
    'RGB': cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB,  # Red, Green, Blue
    'HSV': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV,  # Hue, Saturation, Value
    'HLS': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS,  # Hue, Lightness, Saturation
    'YUV': cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV,  # Y = Luminance , U, V = Chrominance color components   
}

dictionary_of_channels = {
    'channel_1': 0,
    'channel_2': 1,
    'channel_3': 2,
}

dictionary_of_statistics = {
    'min': np.min,
    'max': np.max,
    'mean': np.mean,
    'median': np.median,
    'std': np.std,
}

# creates column names in the same order as loops below
cols = [f'{s}_{c}_{cs}' for s in dictionary_of_statistics for c in dictionary_of_channels for cs in dictionary_of_color_spaces]
# creates empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(column=cols)


# get filenames inside training folders for day and night
path_training_day = './day_night_images/training/day/'
path_training_night = './day_night_images/training/night/'
filenames_training_day = [file for file in os.listdir(path_training_day)]
filenames_training_night = [file for file in os.listdir(path_training_night)]

for filename in filenames_training_day:
    row = []  # row for the current image - to be populated with stat values
    image = cv2.imread(path_training_day + filename)
    for color_space in dictionary_of_color_spaces:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, dictionary_of_color_spaces[color_space])
        for channel in dictionary_of_channels:
            for statistic in dictionary_of_statistics:
                row.append(dictionary_of_statistics[statistic](image[:,:,dictionary_of_channels[channel]]))
    row_series = pd.Series(row, index=cols, name=filename)
    df = df.append(row_series)
```

This code casts the filename of each image as the index of each row in the final df. If you don't want that, cast the index to a new column (`df['filename'] = df.index`) and use pandas.reset_index afterwards (`pd = pd.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The data frame was created. I had to fix two things `# creates column names in the same order as loops below
cols = ['{}_{}_{}'.format(s, c, cs) for s in dictionary_of_statistics for c in dictionary_of_channels for cs in dictionary_of_color_spaces]
# creates empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)`. The problem is that the created data frame is empty.

Comment: Yes I forgot to catch the returned df when I appended the row - I edited the code a bit and added this in as well. In the list comprehension I used [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) for formatting, but you do nedd Python >= 3.6 for that.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :D.